# Submit a time stamp along with a string value in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I'm new to SoapUI and I have to find a solution to the following question.

In my GET method I need to send parameter value using custom properties.
The parameter value format is like `"ABC.<Date & Time Stamp>_XYZ"`.
The Date & Time Stamp is system generated and I don't have access to that.

What I want to know is how can I set up this parameter in Custom properties section.

If it's possible to send any value as the date and time that's also fine (Such as `"ABC.*_XYZ"`)

Comment: if this solves your problem,, please upvote if not you can comment on the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property at Project/suite/testcase level via a groovy script using below commands

You can create any custom string using code

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("timeStamp","ABC.<Date & Time Stamp>_XYZ")
```

Above is just sample you can add time using variables

Also you can manually set custom properties by selecting testcase/suite/project level

[image]

Now to use the property you can use below like code

```
 ${#Project#timeStamp}
```

[image]

Now if i show, Raw the property is being replaced

[image]